# Cracking a 4-digit passcode

Tags: password-recovery

I let a small child play on my pc and he accidentally, I don't know how, put a 4 digit passcode on my mac. I can unlock it using the watch, but I need to know the passcode to remove it. Any advice on how I should install a macro and use it on my pc to find it? I have unlimited tries without any waiting after a try.
After looking up, he blocked my screen time, that I've been using to know when to stop since my schedule is busy. Anyhow, can someone help?

Comment: Might be better on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can't set up a screentime passcode without first entering your Apple ID & password, so the scenario seems unlikely… however

From Apple KB - [If you have forgotten your Screen Time passcode](https://support.apple.com/HT211021)

- Make sure that your Mac is updated to macOS Catalina 10.15.4 or later.
- Choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, then click Screen Time.
- Click  Options in the lower-left corner.
- Click Change Passcode, then click Forgot Passcode.
- Enter the Apple ID and password* that you used to set up the Screen Time passcode.
- Enter a new Screen Time passcode, then enter it again to confirm.
- If you have Share Across Devices turned on, your new Screen Time passcode will automatically update on those devices after you've reset it.